# ImportError: cannot import name 'backend'

Tags: python, keras

I encounter an ImportError when importing `backend` from `keras`

```
from keras import backend
```

The output is

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/utils/conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 88, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import keras
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import applications
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/applications/__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.applications.densenet import DenseNet121
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/applications/densenet/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras.applications.densenet import decode_predictions
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/applications/densenet.py", line 30, in     module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras import backend as K
ImportError: cannot import name 'backend'
```

I don't understand which may be the problem.

Comment: try upgrading tensorflow `sudo pip install tensorflow --upgrade`

Answer (score 6):

I have solved by uninstalling `keras` and `tensorflow`, removing their directories in the `site-packages` folder and then installing them again.

```
pip3 uninstall tensorflow
pip3 uninstall keras
rm -r /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras*
rm -r /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Keras*
rm -r /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow*
pip3 install tensorflow
pip3 install keras
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import tensorflow
from tensorflow.compat.v1.keras.backend import set_session
```

this worked in tensorflow==2.2

Comment: m using 1.15.. any idea how can i do that with that verion?